Problem with loading Images to my PDF with iTextSharp
I need to create a PDF File for my web-app with iTextSharp. The pdf file got about 100 pages. Every page got 2 pictures in it. The pictures are in .png and about 500kb to 900 kb big.
When creating the pdf file I realized that if there are too many pictures, the PDF will not open or show anything at all in my web-app. If the total amount of pictures are below 50 then it will show everything correct. So I guess I have a problem with the pdf when I have to many pictures in it.
The code looks like this:
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw;
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Reflection;

public class PDFGenerator
{
    private ProjectBaseModel _project;
    private ProjectDTOModel _projectDTO;
    private List<QuestionModel> _questions;
    private List<AnswerModel> _answers;

   public async Task ViewPdf(IJSRuntime js, string idIFrame, ProjectBaseModel BaseProject,    ProjectDTOModel DTOProject, List<QuestionModel> QuestionsList, List<AnswerModel> AnswersList)
  {
    _project = BaseProject;
    _projectDTO = DTOProject;
    _questions = QuestionsList;
    _answers = AnswersList;

    js.InvokeVoidAsync("ViewPdf",
        idIFrame,
        Convert.ToBase64String(PDFReport())
        );
  }
  
   private byte[] PDFReport()
  {
     MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
     //Setting Size and Format
     //Setting Header and Footer
     pdf.Open();
     // adding foreach loops 
     // Now adding the pictures in a Table
         AddImageToTable(mainTable,questionImagePath,roundRectangle,maxWidth,maxHeight,fontStyleNormalText);
 mainTable.AddCell(emptyCell);
 AddImageToTable(mainTable, answerImagePath, roundRectangle, maxWidth, maxHeight, fontStyleNormalText);
 pdf.Add(mainTable);

// after every foreach loop create new page:
 pdf.NewPage();
// at the end:
pdf.Close();

return memoryStream.ToArray();

}

// Add Image:
    private void AddImageToTable(PdfPTable table, string imagePath, IPdfPCellEvent cellEvent, float maxWidth, float maxHeight, Font fontStyle)
    {
        
        try
        {
            
            Image image = Image.GetInstance(imagePath);
            image.ScaleToFit(maxWidth, maxHeight);
                image.Alignment = Image.ALIGN_CENTER | Image.ALIGN_MIDDLE;

                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(image)
                {
                    CellEvent = cellEvent,
                    Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER,
                    Padding = 5,
                    HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER,
                    VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_MIDDLE
                };

                table.AddCell(cell);
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("No Picture available", fontStyle))
            {
                CellEvent = cellEvent,
                Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER,
                Padding = 5,
                HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER,
                VerticalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_MIDDLE
            };

            table.AddCell(cell);
        }

    }
   
}


I also tried to compress the pictures and format it to .jpeg. It helps a little bit but actually I need the pictures in good quality. How can I create this pdf with so many pictures?
It does not appear any error code. The Frame just not open at all in my web app razor page. ( Using Blazor Server)
If anybody have an idea or need more information to solve this. I would really appreciate it.
Thanks
I tried to compress the pictures in Size and Quality. It helps but is not the solution I need because it fails anyway with more then 100 pictures.
I expect to find a solution to add about 200 pictures in my PDF with good Quality
